# how can i use django form validation

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms

I am trying to use Django form and validation is not working.
django version 3.2
I tried different methods and still, none of them worked for me.

```
from django import forms
from django.core import validators
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


#Custom_Validator
def check_size(value):
    if len(value) < 6:
        raise forms.ValidationError("value is short")


class UserForm(forms.Form):
    firstName = forms.CharField()
    LastName = forms.CharField(validators = [check_size, ])
    password = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput, validators = [check_size, ])



    def clean_firstName(self):
        inputfirstName = self.cleaned_data['firstName']
        if len(inputfirstName)>5:
            raise ValidationError("reached max length")
        return inputfirstName
```

index.html which i created under templates

```
<h1> User form </h1>


<form method='post'>

  {{form.as_p}}
  {% csrf_token %}
<input type ="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

views.py of application

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from . import forms

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return HttpResponse("Home page")

def formview(request):
    form = forms.UserForm()

    return render (request,'appForm/index.html',{'form':form})
```

urls.py of application

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', views.home),
    path('form/', views.formview),
]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzhGl.png)

Comment: Please share details on what you tried, the error message, how you call the validation, etc.

Comment: when I run this Django project, on a web form is displayed, when I tries to enter a value more than 5 for first name and less than 6 for Lastname and password
it didn't work for me.
NO error logs on terminal as i am not using those value anywhere
I tried code from this site as well: https://data-flair.training/blogs/django-forms-handling-and-validation/

Answer (score 0):

`form.is_valid()` was missing from views.py. As soon as I added it, all of the validation started working.